# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
C:\Users\lucks\OneDrive\Desktop\intern\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-22:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

**Image link is here**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUkHi.png
**I dont have that "flutterlocalnotifications" receiver in my manifest. So where do i add that explicit value???**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373944/flutter-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for)

Answer (score 35):

<s>Try adding this in AndroidManifest.xml. Inside `<application> .... </application>` tag.</s>

```
   <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
              android:exported="true">   
    </receiver>
```

### Update:

To explain the issue, from Android 12, for the application components such as Activity, BroadCast Receiver, Service.. one must explicitly add `android:exported=""` flag in Manifest Component. [Source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

This can be true or false.

If it is marked as true, other apps/system can start the particular component via Intent.

For example, for Launcher Activity we need to mark the activity as `android:exported="true"` . So that system launcher/ other launcher apps can start application by Intent calling the launcher activity.

In most cases, it wont be necessary to mark it as true.

In this case, adding exported = false also will work. So it is recommended to make it as false.

```
   <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
              android:exported="false">   
    </receiver>
```

Actually these changee for Android 12 **flutter_local_notifications** plugin as already added and fix is available on latest versions.

But when you add the package via  `flutter pub add flutter_local_notifications`, it is only adding old version of the plugin. In my case it was downloading version `8.2.0` , but latest available version is `13.0.0` at the time of writing the answer.
So when I explicitly made it to `13.0.0`, this issue won't come.

The reason for flutter adding an older version might be the dependency of other packages.

So finally , to conclude, making `flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0` explicitly in `pubspec.yaml` will solve this issue.

Comment: after add this code working fine for me.. thanks

Comment: Nice , working for me.

Comment: its working, can you explain what does it do?

Comment: Still working - I'm using `5.0.0+2` version of the package due to some reason. But this thing still works. Thanks!

Comment: @Gowthanm Gowthanm  - Please share your AndroidManifest.xml file screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines in your android manifiest file

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
          android:exported="true">   
</receiver>
```