# AndroidManifest build error when using flutter_local_notification: Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, flutter-notification

I am working on a Flutter Application where I want to use the **flutter_local_notifications** with **Firebase Cloud Messaging**. When I added the following code to my main.dart-

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  showFlutterNotification(message);
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

/// Create a [AndroidNotificationChannel] for heads up notifications
late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title

    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
  ///
  /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
  /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
  /// heads up notifications.
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channel.description,
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Initialize the [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin] package.
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  if (!kIsWeb) {
    await setupFlutterNotifications();
  }
```

I got an error-

```
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>.  Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
```

I read several posts and found out that I have to add **android:exported="true"** in **AndroidManifest.xml**. After adding-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blog_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   <application
        android:label="blog_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But, I am still getting the same error after adding the **exported** property to the Manifest file. There is only MainActivity and no other component. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check this ->

[android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73644680/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-element-receivercom-dext)

[Flutter: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373944/flutter-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for)

there's also a video for same problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fma_umbAe6A

and a snippet

```
   <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
              android:exported="true">   
    </receiver>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank You. It worked. I had surfed the web but did not come across these posts.