# Uploading app on play store failing due error in AndroindManifest file

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

i need some help with this error from google play when am trying to upload my flutter app to the store. it says [image]

I have followed the instructions from the android docs of adding the android:exported="true" in the main activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file but the app is still being flaged in the google developer console. Below is the manifest file. Could I be missing something.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hudomain.org">
   <application
        android:label="HUDO Centre"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                android:exported="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Probably one of your packages adds something to your manifest. Are you using flutter_local_notifications  package by any chance? If so, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373944/flutter-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for

Answer (score 0):

Check individual third-party library manifest files if there is any activity, service, or receiver using then you have to override the same activity, service, or receiver in your main manifest file aswell

Answer (score 0):

you are using pakage that will not be fully integrated with anroid 12 so i advice you to check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70957174/15029896